# Strange appearance of WPF DatePicker

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, datepicker

In my WPF application on .NET 4.0, I'm using two `DatePicker`s and two `TextBlock`s in a horizontal `StackPanel`, and it looks like this:

[image]

In the left `DatePicker`, I experimented with a higher font size. Apart from that, there are no special settings or styles.

The buttons are aligned to the `TextBlock`s, but the text in the `DatePicker` is not.

**Any idea how to change the alignment of the date text?**

**EDIT:** Here's my XAML:

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                >
        <TextBlock Text="from " />
        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding FromDate, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="14" />
        <TextBlock Text=" until " />
        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding ToDate, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Could you post your xaml.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks Jorge, it was a `Button` style in the App.xaml:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 5 10 5" />
    </Style>
```

This style applied to the button inside of the `DatePicker` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are working with textblocks then you could try something like this.

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="40" Margin="10">
        <Border Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="#FF2A2A89" BorderThickness="2">
        <TextBlock Width="150" Text="Testing" TextAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>
        <DatePicker VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Name="datepicker" />
    </StackPanel>
```

The content it's really just for demonstrating. You should get something like this:

[image]

However If you are just showing the date why don't you use the datepicker with the default settings? It shows the selected date by default.

Another way to do it, you could use textbox instead of textblocks and set IsReadOnly as 
true. I'm assuming you are using textblocks so they are not editable. Using textboxes you can set VerticalContentAlignment="Center" and that's it.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion about `VerticalContentAlignment="Center"`, but that didn't help either. The text is still misaligned. And yes, I'm using `TextBlock`s (see first sentence of my post)

Comment: I don't see what can be causing that. Setting the VerticalContentAlignment on the datepicker does it for me. Perhaps there is something else on the xaml code. Is there any property on code behind setting that? That stackpanel is inside any container?